# Type-Hinting JSON Object Rigorously

Tags: python, annotations, type-hinting, python-typing, python-3.11

I have a function in my program that takes a JSON as one of its parameters, and I wanted to annotate my function signature as such. I recalled that the `loads()` function from the built-in `json` module takes in a `str`, `bytes`, or a `bytearray` (which aren't even annotated themselves), but the return type on the module's function isn't type hinted. As such, I'm unsure of how to go about type-hinting my params.

The `json.loads()` function in question:

```py
def loads(s, *, cls=None, object_hook=None, parse_float=None,
        parse_int=None, parse_constant=None, object_pairs_hook=None, **kw):
    # function code is here
```

I felt like simply using `typing.Any` was a bit too vague for the purpose of my function, as it demands a specific structure to execute properly (I'm literally pulling in a dictionary within a dictionarywithin a list within a dictionary).

My function in question:

```py
def get_order_list(json_response: <type desired>, *, time_r: int = 60, buyers: bool = False) -> list[int]:
    # code
```

I then set about trying to rigorously annotate the one parameter as such:

```py
def get_order_list(json_response: list[dict[str, None | str | bool | int | dict[str, str | int | bool]]], *, time_r: int = 60, buyers: bool = False) -> list[int]:
    # code
```

But this just looks overcomplicated and ugly. So now I'm at a crossroads. Should I settle with typing.Any, or should I use my convoluted mess of type-hinting?

---

One more thing to mention, would it be wise to document the structure in which the json input should be? If so, should that be within the docstring of the function, the docstring of the file itself, or within a separate file?

Comment: So the json can be anything, not a particular structure (or is it always the same `list[dict[...]]` as described in the question? If the json contains data for a certain model, you could use [pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/), which can parse from json and has type hinting as well as some validation.

Comment: @RolandDeschain the structure of the JSON remains consistent-(ish). All keys are identical on each API call, but the order of the keys themselves is jumbled. Sometimes the key `name` comes first and `id` second, other times the key `id` comes first and ` name` second. But overall, the types remain constant.

Comment: yes pydantic is perfect for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I settle with `typing.Any`, or should I use my convoluted mess of type-hinting?

I think you should **avoid [`Any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Any) as much as possible** (see [these](https://typing.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/best_practices.html#using-any-and-object) recommendations also). It is too often used as a cop-out of actually thinking about your data types. I also don't think your type hint is a convoluted mess. It is just formatted and structured sub-optimally in my opinion.

At the minimum, you could use line breaks and indentation for improved readability:

```py
def get_order_list(
    json_response: list[
        dict[
            str,
            None | str | bool | int | dict[
                str,
                str | int | bool
            ]
        ]
    ],
    *,
    time_r: int = 60,
    buyers: bool = False,
) -> list[int]:
    ...
```

Aside from that, you should definitely remove redundancies in your type unions. An example is using a union of types `S | T`, when `S` is a subtype of `T`. In that case just use `T`.

`bool` is a subtype of `int` (check it with `issubclass`), so you can drop the `bool` from the unions:

```py
def get_order_list(
    json_response: list[
        dict[
            str,
            None | str | int | dict[str, str | int]
        ]
    ],
    *,
    time_r: int = 60,
    buyers: bool = False,
) -> list[int]:
    ...
```

Then you might want to use (explicit) [type aliases](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeAlias) to abstract some of the details a bit and reduce repetition. I would also suggest to always place `None` last in a type union, but this may just be my preference:

```py
from typing import TypeAlias

StrInt: TypeAlias = str | int


def get_order_list(
    json_response: list[
        dict[
            str,
            StrInt | dict[str, StrInt] | None
        ]
    ],
    *,
    time_r: int = 60,
    buyers: bool = False,
) -> list[int]:
    ...
```

And at best, those nested types actually get some semantic names/aliases. Here you did not yet provide enough information, so the best I can do is provide some generic names like this:

```py
from typing import TypeAlias

StrInt: TypeAlias = str | int
ValueType: TypeAlias = StrInt | dict[str, StrInt] | None
ItemType: TypeAlias = dict[str, ValueType]


def get_order_list(
    json_response: list[ItemType],
    *,
    time_r: int = 60,
    buyers: bool = False,
) -> list[int]:
    ...
```

But if you can name those appropriately, not only will this be more concise in the actual function signature, but it will also be much clearer to anyone reading the code, what those types actually *mean*. Which leads into your second question.

---

> would it be wise to document the structure in which the json input should be?

The better you name things in your code, the less comments and documentation you will need. Obviously documentation is necessary, but you will be able to leverage the names you already defined to make it much more concise and precise.

In this case, you will be able to refer to some of your type aliases directly, writing things like this:

*`json_response` should be a list of "items"; an item is a dictionary with string-keys, where each value is a "value"; a value can be either a string, an integer, a dictionary of strings or integers or `None`.*

I am again deliberately using generic terms like "item" and "value", for which you can substitute something with actual meaning in your specific context.

Lastly, I would advise **not** calling that parameter `json_response` in the first place because that is a confusing and frankly incorrect name for what that object will contain. JSON as you know is just a specific text format. It would make sense to call that parameter this way, if you expected the argument to be a `str` of actual JSON.

But you **don't** expect that. Your function expects built-in Python types that you can lay out very precisely (as above). And your function is (and should be) agnostic about where those objects come from - a parsed JSON file or anywhere else. It would work the same, regardless of where that list of dictionaries etc. came from. Therefore the "JSON" in the parameter name is simply misleading and unnecessary. "Response" may be sensible in terms of meaning, again I don't know the context.

And yes, I would suggest always fully documenting your parameters (and their more complex types if necessary) in the function's **docstring**. This does not mean you should avoid mentioning that somewhere else as well, but the docstring should explain **everything** one needs to know to use that function.

In summary, I would probably write it something like this:

```py
from typing import TypeAlias

StrInt: TypeAlias = str | int
ValueType: TypeAlias = StrInt | dict[str, StrInt] | None
ItemType: TypeAlias = dict[str, ValueType]


def get_order_list(
    response: list[ItemType],
    *,
    time_r: int = 60,
    buyers: bool = False,
) -> list[int]:
    """
    Does X, Y, and Z and returns a list of ...
    
    [Some additional context/info for when/how this function should be used,
    expanding on the first sentence of the docstring,
    which should be a one-liner.] 

    Args:
        response:
            a list of "items"; an item should be a dictionary with string-keys,
            where each value is a "value"; a value can be either a string,
            an integer, a dictionary of strings or integers or `None`
        time_r:
            time for ...; 60 by default
        buyers:
            Whether or not ...; `False` by default
    
    Returns:
        List of integers, where each one represents ...
    """
    ...
```

I have omitted a lot of *"in general"*, *"typically"*, and *"my advice would be"* clauses in my answer here. But I think it goes without saying that most of this is at least somewhat subjective or conventional.

---

**PS**:

All that being said, I am a big fan of [Pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/) and agree completely with Roland in the comments that it seems like yours is a prime use case for it. Especially if the objects involved mostly follow a certain schema, you could define **models** for what I called `ValueType` and `ItemType` instead to encapsulate their meaning even better.

Not to mention it offers validation and provides much better type safety overall.

But I think most of what I wrote above still applies regardless of whether you use Pydantic models or built-in types.